Where does one go to view the query error?
After I imported an Excel file into Power BI, the Query Editor showed one error. I then clicked on "View Error" in the following window.

Then it brought up the Query Editor. But I don't see in the Query Editor what the error message is.

Thank you for your help!

Go to edit query. You should be able to see the rows with the error separately in Queries section in the left hand side.
In Power Query, you can encounter two types of errors:

Step-level errors
Cell-level errors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/dealing-with-errors
